# Can not overlay a image on Appbar of my screen. (React-Native, react-native-paper)

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I tried to overlap an image on **Appbar** Component and it's not happening.

Here is my code...

```
<View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#F6F8FB'}}>
        <Appbar.Header style={styles.appHeader}>
          <Appbar.BackAction />
        </Appbar.Header>
        <Image
          source={require('../../../resource/images/LivingRoom.png')}
          style={styles.imageStyle}
        />
</View>
```

Here is the CSS for the same.

```
  appHeader: {
    backgroundColor: '#184DB8',
    height: (15 / 100) * height,
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  imageStyle: {
    width: '100%',
    height: (25 / 100) * height,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 50,
    borderTopRightRadius: 40,
  },
```

I need Help!!

[image]

Like this Image

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `postion:'absolute` to imageStyle.

```
imageStyle: {
    postion: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: (25 / 100) * height,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 50,
    borderTopRightRadius: 40,
  },
```

now you can play with image position by edit `top`.

Comment: Nope, the image just disappears and the  `top: value` doesn't work. Also tried `marginTop` but didn't work

Comment: what's the value of height? do check your 'height'. let's make your height:100 and check

Comment: Height is my mobile screen height

Answer (score 0):

Write `</Appbar.Header>` after the `<Image>` tag

```
<View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#F6F8FB'}}>
        <Appbar.Header style={styles.appHeader}>
            <Appbar.BackAction />
            <Image
               source={require('../../../resource/images/LivingRoom.png')}
               style={styles.imageStyle}
            />
       </Appbar.Header>

</View>
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: I am sorry, write please </Appbar.Header> tag after the image ending tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your problem by removing "flex: 1" from your view container. The result I got was the following:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyGI8.jpg)

This is the code:

```
<View style={styles.header}>
  <Appbar.Header style={styles.appHeader}>
    <Appbar.BackAction />
  </Appbar.Header>
  <Image
    source={require('../../assets/room.jpg')}
    style={styles.imageStyle}
  />
</View>
```

And the styles:

```
  header: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#184DB8',
    shadowColor: 'transparent',
  },
  appHeader: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#184DB8',
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: 'transparent',
  },
  imageStyle: {
    flex: 0,
    width: '100%',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 50,
    borderTopRightRadius: 40,
  }
```

(PS: sorry if my English writing is somewhat confusing, I'm learning it)
(PS2: I am new to the world of react and I couldn't remove the shadow that the header has, an apology)